# Two ways data binding - nothing happens

Tags: blazor

I am using .NET 8 and created a Blazor application (WebAssembly) and placed the following markup and code in `Home.razor`:

```
<input @bind="Title" />

<h2>Hello, @Title</h2>

@code {
    private string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

And I don't see any changes when I write something in the input, why?

[image]

My code is almost the same like here:

https://www.learnblazor.com/data-binding

and here:

https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/blazor/blazor-two-way-data-binding-example/

Here is the film:
https://imgur.com/a/QqRKS3D

The solution: create Blazor STANDALONE application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is valid and works. You maybe want to make it bind `oninput`. Which will result in change when you type (not after leaving the input field as it is in your version.)

```
<input @bind="Title" @bind:event="oninput" />
```

[Live version](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/GeYGGwFB316dm8H507).

If it still doesn't work you probably using SSR instead of wasm interactivity.

Comment: I added a film in the main post. I have "AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents" in Program.cs.

Comment: Yeah, now that is clear you are not using wasm interactivity. You either have to have blazor wasm standalone app (you have index.html in your wwwroot folder) or you have created Blazor Web App. In that case you need to place the Home page into Client project and place the `@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly` on the top of the page. If you don't have the client project you have to add it, or use the template with interactivity when creating the solution.

Comment: Thank you, I created Blazor Standalone App as you said and now it works :)